# *ngFor throwing invalid pipe argument AngularFireList

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, ngfor

I am having trouble understanding why my *ngFor is throwing me an invalid pipe argument with async and without it I get an error stating NgFor only supports binding to iterables such as Arrays. I have basically the same code on a separate page and it works as intended but for some reason on this page I get these errors.

I know that the information is there since when I log it to the console it prints the data from my database.

Employee-Detail.ts page - The param being received in the constructor is a snapshot of the item that comes from my firebase data reference.

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Profile } from '../../models/profile';
    import { CheckIn } from '../../models/check-in';
    import { CheckOut } from '../../models/check-out';
    import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 
    'angularfire2/database';
    import { CheckInDetailsPage } from '../../pages/check-in-details/check-in-
    details';
    import { CheckOutDetailsPage } from '../../pages/check-out-details/check-
    out-details';


    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-employee-detail',
      templateUrl: 'employee-detail.html',
    })
    export class EmployeeDetailPage {

      checkInList: Observable<CheckIn[]>;
      checkOutList: Observable<CheckOut[]>;
      public profile: any;  
      constructor(
         public navCtrl: NavController,
         public navParams: NavParams,
         public database: AngularFireDatabase,
       ) {
             this.profile = this.navParams.data;
             console.log(this.profile.firstName);

             this.checkInList = this.profile.checkInList;
             console.log(this.checkInList);

      }


      checkInDetails() {
        this.navCtrl.push('CheckInDetailsPage');
      }


      checkOutDetails() {
        this.navCtrl.push('CheckOutDetailsPage');
      }

    }
```

And my employee-detail.html page

```
    <ion-header>
        <ion-navbar>
          <ion-title>Employee Details</ion-title>
        </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>


    <ion-content padding>
         <h1>
           {{profile.firstName}} {{profile.lastName}}
         </h1>
         <ion-list>
              <ion-item>
                  <p>Email:
                      <strong>{{profile.email}}</strong>
                  </p>

                  <p>Checked In:
                      <strong *ngIf = "profile.checkedIn === true "> Yes 
                      </strong>
                      <strong *ngIf = "profile.checkedIn === false "> No 
                      </strong>
                  </p>      
                  <button ion-button block (click)="checkInDetails()">
                      Check In List
                  </button>

                  <button ion-button block (click)="checkOutDetails()">
                       Check Out List
                  </button>

           </ion-item>

         </ion-list>


        <ion-list>

            <ion-item *ngFor="let checkIn of checkInList">
              <p>Time:
                <strong>
                    {{checkIn.time}}
                </strong> 
              </p>
            </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```

[image: Console Log]

Comment: can you display checkInList from the developer console?

Comment: Added it into the post, thanks for reminding me forgot to add it in.

Comment: Your `checkInList` is an object, not an array

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't quite that it's an Object, but that it's an observable. Unless you're subscribing to it or mapping, you can't get it's value. To resolve I suggest:

```
checkIns: CheckIn[];

constructor () {
    this.checkInList.subscribe(ci => this.checkIns = ci)
}
```

Then you should be able to iterate through CheckIns as expected.

Comment: I'm getting an error that subscribe is not a function. I tried using `this.checkInList.subscribe(ci => this.checkIns = ci);` and the same from my navparams.data but both threw the same error

Comment: You have to import it from the rxjs library. `import {  Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'`

Comment: Now I am getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined. I figured it was because the checkIns array wasn't initialized so I set it to null but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you subscribe to it after the variable was set with `this.checkInList = this.profile.checkInList;`

Comment: `this.checkInList = this.profile.checkInList;
    this.checkInList.subscribe(ci => this.checkIns = ci);`

Comment: I also tried with snapshotChanges and mapping it but also get the same error with those classes. `this.checkInList = this.profile.checkInList.snapshotchanges()
      .map(
        changes => {
          return changes.map(c => ({
            key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
          }))
        }
    ) ;`

Comment: Okay so I thought of this, is it bad that I am just passing the observable directly. Should I pass the key and then get the reference in the next page with the key?

Comment: Honestly if it's static data and you already have it then yes. Observables are best used for data that changes or when you're waiting for data from an async method. Every time you subscribe to an observable it fires off the underlying code which can be unnecessary and undesired.

Comment: Okay so you'd recommend just getting the reference with the key?